# How to grep lines that begin with a specified string and end with another specified string?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

For example how would I get lines that begin with foo and end with bar?

Example lines:

```
foo12345abar
fooabcdbar
fooy7ghqqbar
```

This does not seem to work

```
grep '^foo[.]*bar$'
```

What is the correct regex?

Comment: Try it in two greps (using a pipe), something like `cat file | grep "^foo" | grep "bar$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your expression does not work is because `[.]` represents a dot, literally. Your expression would match strings that look like this:

```
foo.......bar
foo...bar
boobar
```

To make it work remove square brackets `[]` around the dot meta-character:

```
^foo.*bar$
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yI2kX8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^foo.*?bar$
```

Here is the working [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xV1pI4/2).